# Batch rename files with Mac Bash,while the dir index should be recorded

Tags: bash, macos

I need to batch rename images with Mac Bash,while the directory index should be recorded.

To rename files ,turn

```
Root---A----0.png
|      |
|      ----1.png
|
-------B----0.png
       |
       ----1.png
```

to

```
Root---A----0_0.png
|      |
|      ----0_1.png
|
-------B----1_0.png
       |
       ----1_1.png
```

Here is my code, it is ok to deal with the situation that `dir` A has a name of spacing.

```
Base=$(pwd)
num=0
IFS='
' # split on newline only
for path in *
    do
    if [[ -d $path ]]; then
        NewPath="${Base}/${path}"
        for f in "$NewPath"/* 
            do
            dir=`dirname "$f"`
            base=`basename "$f"`
            name="${dir}/${num}_${base}"
            mv ${f} "$name"
        done 
        num=$((num + 1))
    fi
done
```

Any way to do it more brilliantly? `find` is a good option to handle files recursively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limit globbing to directories only by appending a slash:  `for dir in */`

If you `cd` into subdirectories, you don't need to construct a new path for each file.  If you `cd` inside a subshell with `( cd … )`, the original directory will be restored when subshell exits.  Make sure to increment `n` *outside* of the subshell, or the new value will be lost!

The `IFS=` is not needed; bash will split the filenames properly.  You just need to quote the variable when you refer to it.

```
n=0
for d in */ ; do
    ( cd "$d" && for f in * ; do mv  "$f" $n"_$f" ; done )
    (( n++ ))
done
```